# How to send a get request and recieve json data in php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I actually want to know how to create this request in php

```
GET /current_user HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://burp/show/1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Cookie: ...
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

it is very important to add the line

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

in the request and also i need to get the json response which is like this

```
{"csrf_token":"..............","signed_in?":true,"disclosure_directory_submissions_enabled":false,"new_feature_article_available":false,"bounty_statistics_enabled":true,"pro_community_enabled":false,"davr_enabled":false,"is_member_of_teams":false,"can_request_endorsements":false,"whitelisted_team_ids":[],"edit_unclaimed_profiles":false,"signal":null,"email":"........","id":.....,"username":"....","name":"Mohamed Sherif","bio":"","url":".","profile_picture_urls":{"small":"..","medium":".."}}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: if you have it on the server, use curl: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php

Comment: You can't create an `XMLHttpRequest ` in PHP.  You can generate an XHR request from a client, not a server.

Comment: can you please explain more cant i even add this line in javascript or something

Comment: can you just give me a piece of code even for the rest of the request without the XMLHttpRequest part @Giladd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl to send the request normally. For passing headers, use below example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/current_user");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //to get return value from server

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
));
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $output;
```